# How to calculate the pairwise LD for the given data?

Tags: r, correlation, genetics

I have the following data, which is the output from the [MS Hudson](http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/18/2/337.full.pdf+html) software.

```
segsites: 6 
positions: 0.1256 0.3122 0.3218 0.4970 0.5951 0.7943 
001010 
110101 
010100 
001010 
010100
```

I want to make an R function to calculate the R-Squared across pairs separated by <10% (the difference between positions of SNPs must be < 0.10) of the simulated genomic region.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: @onestop This is a software for population genetics, http://j.mp/a75Z4Y

Comment: I've written a python script to calculate LD (r square) in a determined range of distance. you may first phase your data by beagle v3.2 and then give phased file along with mapfile (plink mapfile) and determine a size (e.g. 500 kb). this program calculate r2 and deliver you a txt file which contains all pairwise LD between 2 snp in your determined range. if you need, don't hesitate to contact me.

Answer (score 4):

I know the `LDheatmap` function/package can calculate the pairwise LDs, see `ldhm$LDmatrix` in the example below.  I'm not familiar with the software you mention or how to get data into the required format for `LDheatmap`.

```
> library(LDheatmap)
> data(CEUData)
> ldhm <- LDheatmap(CEUSNP, genetic.distances=CEUDist, LDmeasure="r")
> head(ldhm$LDmatrix, 1)
          rs4615512   rs2283089 rs1894731 rs2283092 rs2283093 rs6978939 rs6979287
rs4615512        NA 0.003329066 0.1657227 0.1657227 0.1269654 0.1657227 0.1209495
          rs6979572 rs2283094 rs2283095 rs6467111 rs1111183 rs2237789 rs2299531 rs2299532
rs4615512 0.1197102 0.8395061 0.1197102  0.099289 0.3470553 0.1197102 0.3746656 0.3470553
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various R/Bioconductor packages that allow you to compute pairwise correlation for SNPs in linkage disequilibrium, see the CRAN Task View [Statistical Genetics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Genetics.html). As I worked directly with whole genome scan, I've been mainly using `snpMatrix`, but [LDheatmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LDheatmap/index.html) or [mapLD](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapLD/index.html) are fine. However, usually they expect genotype data (AA, AB, or BB), so I guess you will have to first convert your binary-encoded haplotype... About the filter on location, I also guess you just have to consider the pairwise $R^2$ or $D'$ for proximal SNPs (usually, we draw a so-called heatmap of pairwise LD, which is roughly speaking the lower-diag elements of the correlation matrix, so you just have to consider the very first off diagonal elements).

**Update**

Now that I've read some papers, I'm not sure you will achieve your goals with the aforementioned method. To my knowledge, few packages allow to cope with multiallelic loci or haplotype blocks, one example being the [gap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gap/index.html) package from JH Zhao (see also a review in the [Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v23/i08/paper)). The `LDkl()` function for example computes D' and $\rho$ from a vector of haplotype frequencies, which can easily be plotted using `image()` or `levelplot()` from the `lattice` package.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!  Actually, I do not know how to convert my binary data into genotype data? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @jacki Well, actually it is not very clear to me what's the repeated lines of binary value mean: Does it stand for an haplotype block (1=mutant, 0=ancestral allele) on different chromosomes, simulated for different individuals (each new line starting with //), because in this case the haplotype are of varying size... Is it possible to compute haplotype frequencies easily from your software? Maybe I need to reread some papers and come back to you, but if you have any further information (how do we read the output in terms of haplotype, allele marker, etc.), pls update your original question.

Comment: @chl:  I am trying to do programming in R for haplotype frequencies, for number of segregating sites, etc. 
          SNPs
Ind1   0 0 0 0 1
Ind2   1 0 1 0 0
Ind3   0 1 0 1 0
Ind4   1 1 1 0 0

In above data, each column-wise is SNP and row-wise is individual(Ind1, Ind2,...). As I said before it was simulated on whole genome. The position is normalize random variable from uniform distribution [0,1]. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jacki If I read it correctly, 00001 means 5 markers/alleles with one variant, and you have $n$ such vectors with varying locations for SNP (it was not clear `ms` manual)?

Comment: @chl: Now it is clear to you? How we can covert this binary data into genotype data?

Comment: @chl: thanks for your answer. In R, is it possible to calculate linkage disequilibrium when the a marker is a gene deletion or an ins/del polymorphism ?